# Preventing XSS but still allowing some HTML in PHP

Tags: php, xss

I want to block XSS attacks but I still want to allow HTML tags like `<b><u><i><img><a>` and YouTube video players. I don't want to be open for XSS attacks tho. I am using PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using [htmlpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/), it is the most secure tool to filter html.

I suggest you also to read this [great analysis of HTML sanistisation tools for php](http://blog.astrumfutura.com/archives/431-HTML-Sanitisation-The-Devils-In-The-Details-And-The-Vulnerabilities.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
strip_tags($string, "<b> <u> <i> <img> <a>");
```

This will not prevent someone from using onmouseover etc. though - you have to strip out Javascript.